# Jetbrains Rider: как изменить версию c#?

Tags: c#, jetbrains, rider

Мне нужна версия языка c# 9.0, но у меня более старая версия. Пользуюсь JetBrains Rider - не смогла найти, как обновить версию языка.

Comment: Для .NET 5 по идее C# 9 идет по умолчанию.

Comment: Это делается через LangVersion в csproj https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался хитростю и написал в методе

```
swich (a)
{
case < 5: 
}
```

Так как это используется с 9 версии с#, потом возле знака < нажал Alt + Enter и там можно выбрать изменить версию на 9

Оно меняет только для этого проекта